# Render is different from layout and shading

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, shaders

I'm trying to render a water bottle with Cycles engine, and some water in it. However render is different (the water surface rendered as dark). What's wrong, please advise, thanks.

[image: layout]

[image: shading]

[image: render]

Comment: hello could you please share your file? pack the images if there are some HDRIs

Comment: [blender file and label image](http://emrahcelebi.com/water_bottle.zip)
Because plane texture file is too big I haven't it included in the package and don't think it matters. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have overlapping faces, it creates a bad shading, in *Edit* mode select one of the tris and hide it, then select the big face and delete it:

[image]

Comment: It worked, thanks!